# Nav Bar- Main Menu List Cannot Center - What am I always missing?

Tags: html, css

What's missing that keeps my main menu not centered or aligned with the logo?
I've kept on repeating the same mistake over and over again. I'm still learning HTML. Please help.

I cannot copy the whole code here so please have a look on GitHub.
https://github.com/johnrichtvald/practice/blob/master/1.html

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#header .logoko {
  border: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#header a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

#header #menu,
#header #menu-right {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#header #menu-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>decoded</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="logoko" src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </a>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="menu-right">
      <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: post the code not the repo (just copy to snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`display:flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to  `#header`,`ul`

And instead `float:right` use `margin-left:auto` to `#header #menu-right`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
}

#header .logoko {
  border: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#header a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: flex;
}

#header #menu,
#header #menu-right {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#header #menu-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="logoko" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG0gL.png" alt="Logo">
  </a>

  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="menu-right">
    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```